# React.js + Webpack won't recognize @media expressions

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, sass, webpack-style-loader

I'm currently working on site that runs on React.js (15.6.1) and Webpack 1. I'm using a [SASS-compatible version](https://codepen.io/absolutholz/post/flex-box-grid-with-sass-mixins) of the popular Flexbox Grid. For some reason however it doesn't seem to compile @media expressions like it normally would.

In this example `@include viewport($key);` works as intended but it completely skips the media query.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 48em) {
    @include viewport($key);
}
```

For some reason I don't get any errors. I've tried using [sass-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader) as well as [fast-sass-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-sass-loader) but neither seem to resolve my issue.

I'd be thankful for any helpful advice!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `react-media` npm

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-media